# URL parameters in react without react hooks

Tags: reactjs

In App.js I've this route

```
<Route exact path='/questions/:questionId'>
                  <Details />
                </Route>
```

In HomeListItem.js I've this link

```
<button className='view-poll'>
                        <Link to={`/questions/${questionId}`}>
                            View poll
                        </Link>
```

In Details.js I want to access the questionId,
I tried by doing this ...

```
const { questionId } = this.props.match.params;
```

but I've this error in the browser **TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'props')**

I've used withRouter in Details.js, it's a class component,

```
import { BrowserRouter as withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';  
...
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Details));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BrowserRouter` and `withRouter` are completely different things. `BrowserRouter` is a react component that acts as a context provider. `withRouter` is a function that appends the `match` prop to the component that you give it from the closest parent `BrowserRouter`.

At the moment you're importing `BrowserRouter` as `withRouter`:

```js
import { BrowserRouter as withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

You need to import the `withRouter` wrapper itself:

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Here's an [example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-kepler-h2268) where the "**Test.js**" file is akin to your "**Details.js**" file.